# Worst case for $n$ Poisson trials?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution

I have $n$ Poisson events which occur with parameter $\lambda$. What can I expect the lowest of these to be?

I'd be happy with any reasonable interpretation of the question, including "what is the expectation of the lowest", "what is the median of the lowest", "what is the average of the lowest", etc. In my particular application (shot noise on low-light photos) $n$ is several million and $\lambda$ is at least in the hundreds, so a normal approximation would suit me just fine.

Comment: The minimum of independent exponential random variables is again exponentially distributed with parameter the sum of the parameters.

Comment: @Did: I don't know how to apply that to my problem. I have a Poisson (or essentially normal) distribution, not an exponential one -- I'm counting events, not measuring the time between events.

Comment: Then you (we) need a serious definition of "n Poisson events which occur with parameter λ". What does this mean? Note that "Poisson (or essentially normal) distribution" is another mystery.

Comment: @Did: Let's say $\lambda=1000$ and $n=10^6$. Then I have a million events which are each around 1000. Maybe the lowest of these is 850 and the highest is 1145; the answer I'm looking for is 850. Of course since 1000 is 'big' I might as well use the normal distribution with $\mu=1000$ and $\sigma\approx31.6.$

Comment: If lambda=1000, the events are rather around 1/1000... But anyway this seems to be the situation described in my first comment.

Comment: @Did: You're talking about the time between events, which is (as you say) about 1/1000. I'm talking about the minimal number of events per period, which is a number around 1000 (actually, close to 850 in my example). So you're definitely not talking about the same thing, as we're off by a factor of a million.

Comment: "We are not talking about the same thing" because it is extremely difficult to decipher the exact model you have in mind, based on the text of your question. Unless you remedy this, there is no real question here. Note that you still did not address the two specific points raised in my comment 2015-02-19 22:42:57.

Comment: @Did: I can't see the timestamps for your comments, they display only as "xx minutes ago". But I feel that I've addressed all of your points, both explicitly and with examples. Is there something I can revisit for you?

Comment: No you did not. About time stamps: hover over the "xx minutes ago".

Comment: @Did: "n Poisson events which occur with parameter λ". means that there are n pixels, each of which has about λ photons hitting it. The number of photons is Poisson distributed, but it can be approximated as a normal distribution for the reasons I've given. In particular, there are about nλ total photons but the answer I'm looking for -- the number of photons hitting the least-popular pixel -- is (somewhat) less than λ.